# Плейлист на javascript

Tags: javascript, html

Привет. Я застрял на таком. Создаю музыкальный плеер с плейлистом, т.е. все ссылки на аудиофайлы на странице размещаются в span:

```html
<span class="play-icon" id="play-icon__3" onclick="player.init(this.id);" data-src="/upload/user_music/1/adc4bb35bc5820d48fdd7fbe979b4353.mp3"></span> 
<span class="play-icon" id="play-icon__2" onclick="player.init(this.id);" data-src="/upload/user_music/1/487b38631115d13a7e743d486f975a56.mp3"></span>
```

А чтобы плейлист нормально работал, мне нужно знать, сколько вот таких span генерируется на странице, впоследствии чего из каждого такого вытащить data-src и добавить его в конец массива. Подскажите, пожалуйста, данное решение. Буду признателен за помощь.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ну как бы очень просто узнать количество спанов:

```
$('span.play-icon').length //2
```

На чистом яваскрипте

```
var len = document.getElementsByClassName('d');
len.lenght //2
```

Получить массив значений

```
var len = document.getElementsByClassName('d');
        var arr =[];
        for (var i = 0; i < len.lenght; i++){
            arr.push(len[i].getAttribute('data-src'));
        }
```

Comment: А не используя JQuery, как сосчитать, а потом заполнить массив?

Answer (score 1):

Если все `span` имеют один и тот же класс, то можно воспользоваться методом [`document.getElementsByClassName`](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_document_getelementsbyclassname.asp). Он возвращает "живую" коллекцию, в которой содержатся все тэги (не обязательно `span`), имеющие указанный класс. Число элементов вычисляется при помощи стандартного метода `length`:

```
var spans = document.getElementsByClassName("play-icon");
console.log(spans.length);
```

А вот так можно заполнить массив атрибутами `data-src` этих элементов:

```
var dataSrc = [];
for (var i = 0; i < spans.length; ++i)
    dataSrc.push(spans[i].getAttribute("data-src"));
```

Или чуть похитрее, используя метод `forEach` типа `Array`, появившийся в *ECMAScript 5*:

```
[].forEach.call(spans, function (span) {
    dataSrc.push(span.getAttribute("data-src"));
});
```

---

***Update***

Доказательство того, что этот код рабочий:

```js
function f() {
    var div = document.getElementById("output");
    
    var spans = document.getElementsByClassName("play-icon");
    
    var dataSrc = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < spans.length; ++i)
        dataSrc.push(spans[i].getAttribute("data-src"));
    div.innerHTML = dataSrc;
    
    dataSrc = [];
    [].forEach.call(spans, function (span) {
        dataSrc.push(span.getAttribute("data-src"));
    });
    div.innerHTML += "<br>" + dataSrc;
}
```

```html
<span class="play-icon" data-src="srcA">A</span>
<span class="play-icon" data-src="srcB">B</span>
<span class="play-icon" data-src="srcC">C</span>
<span class="play-icon" data-src="srcD">D</span>
<br>
<br>
<button onclick="f();">Click me!</button>
<div id="output"></div>
```